# Ensuring Eloquent isn't called in controllers

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to structure my application like controller->repositories->model (so controller calls a repository which calls a model). Is there any way to structure my application so eloquent methods are inaccessible in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do so.

1. Create a folder under `app` such as `app/repository`, then add all your repository classes.
2. Modify you `composer.json` file to indicate this new path to be autoloaded.

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           ...
           "app/repository"
       ]
   },
   ```

And you are good to go. Have fun coding!

---

**Note:** You may need to run `php artisan dump-autoload` everytime you add a new class a this new path location.

Comment: That's how to create a repository, I'm looking for a way to make sure future developers don't bypass the repository system in the controllers

Comment: Now I clearly understand your point, I don't think that's possible to has this level of control... In that case the better thing to do is to train your team to follow a code convention to avoid this.